# Returning Array of Objects from PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP class (`POJO_FOO`) which maps to a table (`TABLE_FOO`).

e.g. one row equal to one object of that class.

Now I am writing a manager which returns array of such objects matching a particular query. Using `PDO`, how can I return array of objects ?

When I do simple `fetchAll`, it returns array (representing number of results) of associative array (`column` => `value`). Is there a option in `fetchALL` which can give me result in form of array of objects ?

Comment: wow it works ... don't know why it wasn't working when I tried. anyways .. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use PDO::FETCH_CLASS to hydrate your class with your data :

```
return $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM tablefoo')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'POJO_FOO');
```

it is also useful to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE because it makes the construction of the object more consistent. Habitualy your constructor is called before everything. If you do not use FETCH_PROPS_LATE it will called after your properties are hydrated.

Comment: wow it works ... don't know why it wasn't working when I tried. anyways .. thanks for the answer :)

Comment: a litle comment about PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE

Comment: what will that do ? (FETCH_PROPS_LATE)

Comment: I tried to explain it :
-without PROPS_LATE : PDO hydrates your object and then calls the constructor. If your constructor does call a important initialisation process, it is bad
-with PROPS_LATE : PDO calls your constructor and then hydrate your object : that's consistent and secured.